# Unbind Click Events in Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I can't seem to unbind the click event when using the plotly library, there doesn't seem to be a function for it. I need to select 4 points on a graph and then I don't need the handler anymore.

The example on the [official site](https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/) binds events but doesn't demonstrate a way to get rid of chart click handlers.

For now I'll be implementing a loop in the one handler and it will just ignore clicks beyond the 4 that I need. Doesn't seem efficient though.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/107#issuecomment-279716312 you can use removeListener and removeAllListeners API methods:

```
graphDiv.removeListener("plotly_click", handler);
graphDiv.removeAllListeners("plotly_click");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

You can see added line in js part in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWgQpX).

Related [GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/107) issue